# Unity C# When adding 2 items into a list for some reason the following loop doesn't run?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the following code I have the list "PlayerList" set as a static in another script, to this I am adding 2 items in the start method of their won script, this works perfectly fine for one of them but when i add another the returned value is always (0,0,0) any help would be appreciated.

```c#
Vector3 GetDesiredPosition()
{

    Position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i == ControllsHolder.PlayerList.Count-1; i++) //When multiple players in list it sets position to 0 for some reason?
    {
        if (ControllsHolder.PlayerList[i].Alive)
            Position = new Vector3(Position.x + ControllsHolder.PlayerList[i].transform.position.x, Position.y + ControllsHolder.PlayerList[i].transform.position.y, 0);
        else continue;

    }
    Position = new Vector3(Position.x / (ControllsHolder.PlayerList.Count),Position.y/(ControllsHolder.PlayerList.Count),0);

    return Position;
}
```

Comment: `i < ControllsHolder.PlayerList.Count` not `i == ControllsHolder.PlayerList.Count - 1` ?

Comment: Wait no scratch that i miss read what you wrote sorry, yeah that fixed it thanks!! ^_^

Comment: That's way too much code in one line.